# binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' glm::vec3 in map

Tags: c++, dictionary, caching, key, glm-math

I've been dabbling with discregrids LRUCache, but I'm having trouble getting it working with glm's vec3's. I keep getting a `binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty'` error, even though I've implemented an operator overload for the underlying std:map  [*file.hpp*]:

```
bool operator<(const glm::vec3& lhs, const glm::vec3& rhs)
{
    return lhs.x < rhs.x || lhs.x == rhs.x && (lhs.y < rhs.y || lhs.y == rhs.y && lhs.z < rhs.z);
}

template <typename K, typename V>
class LRUCache
{
    using key_type = K;
    using value_type = V;

    using key_tracker_type = std::list<key_type>;
    using key_to_value_type = std::map<key_type, std::pair<value_type, typename key_tracker_type::iterator>>;
    ...
}
```

```
LRUCache<glm::vec3, double>
```

Comment: I'm assuming line 3 is generating the error? The compiler is telling you the glm::vec3.y class let's call it Foo does not have a function bool  operator<((maybe const) Foo& other)

Comment: Unrelated: The comparison function looks off. Is a `vec3` supposed to be considered less than another just because of its placement?

Comment: From what I've seen it depends on the purpose, this was one of the answer I found on SO so I just rolled with it.

Comment: If the purpose is to be able to store `vec3`s in a map, use an `unordered_map` and implement a hashing function. That should save you from some strange results later.

Comment: Well the thing is I'm using Discregrid for SDF generations, and this is one of the classes that is used there quite a bit. I'd prefer to just be able to create an operator overload and not have to rewrite half of the library.

Comment: _"I'd prefer to just be able to create an operator overload and not have to rewrite half of the library"_ - Sure, but they are not using `map`s where `glm::vec3`s are the keys anywhere, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short form is your `operator<` is not being found due to how ADL works.  In particular, C++ searches the namespaces of the arguments (and their base classes, and other related classes).   You've placed `operator<` in the global namespace, which is not the `glm` namespace.

So, you could either put the comparison in the `glm` namespace (Which I don't really recommend), or create a comparison function object, and use that.

```
struct MyCompare{
  bool operator()(const glm::vec3& lhs, const glm::vec3& rhs) const
  {
     return lhs.x < rhs.x || lhs.x == rhs.x && (lhs.y < rhs.y || lhs.y == 
     rhs.y && lhs.z < rhs.z);
  }
};
```

And then use it with

```
std::map<key_type, std::pair<value_type, typename key_tracker_type::iterator>, MyCompare>
```

If you don't want ordering, you can also look at `unordered_map`, if you can develop a reasonable hashing function (or if it comes with one).